# Task Scheduler

Tags: windows-server-2008, scheduled-task

When setting up a task in Microsoft Windows Server 2008, it fails to run with error:

Task Scheduler failed to launch action XXXXXXX  Additional Data: Error Value: 2147942593

I have tried running in various users etc and providing password etc but it still fails to launch and run

Comment: What happens when you run the task manually?

Comment: Also verify the account you are trying to run the task as has the option to log on locally via the group policy.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to run some 64 bit code on a 32 bit system? I believe the error code means that the action is "not a valid win 32 application."